# Moving div based on dynamic ajax response and comparing to other information on the page

Tags: jquery, grails, html, jquery-animate

I have a page with the below structure (HTML content shortened for readability), where the order of the 'pictureinthread' divs in the DOM when the page is rendered is based on the number of votes in the 'voteamount' child div (which is actually two levels down given the picturemeta div).  The user has the ability to dynamically upvote a given image (via Ajax) which increases its count (the value in 'voteamount').  I would like, if the position of div should change based on the vote, for it to dynamically animate and assume its new proper position.  I already have the ajax working properly and the number in 'voteamount' updating, but my javascript/Jquery experience is not enough to go further, which is to inspect all the other values in the 'voteamount' for the other 'pictureinthread's and do a nice animation if the 'pictureinthread' should move.

Note I realize that currently it could only move one spot, but I would like the ability for it to move anywhere within the list of 'pictureinthread' based on the returned value from the ajax call, as the voting logic will get more complicated.

I am using Grails with the JQuery plugin, and currently the Ajax looks like this for each div as per the below, you can see where I need the help (I'm assuming onComplete is the best point given http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html)

```
<g:remoteLink onComplete="HELP ME HERE!" controller="voting" action="upvote" update="upvotes${pictureInThread.id}" id="${pictureInThread.id}">
```

And my HTML

```
    <div class="pictureinthread" id="..">
        <img src="..." id="..." class="..."/>

        <div class="picturemeta">
            <a href="..ajax call rendered with the g:remotelink..."><img class="thumbsup" src="..."/> <div class="voteamount" id='upvotes+unique...'>3</div></a>     
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="pictureinthread" id="...">
        ..many more like the above..
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, since it's the UX/animation that is important, here's another method:

http://jsfiddle.net/andromedado/jhYd7/

The basic idea is that the function `updatePos` accepts a jQuery wrapped `<div class="pictureinthread">`, and it will animate it into the correct position relative to its immediate siblings. In the jsFiddle I have the event triggered on click, but in your model you would trigger it on ajax update.

#### CSS

```
.rel {postion:relative;}
```

#### JS

```
function getVN($div){
    return parseInt($div.find('.voteamount').text(),10);
}
function sendDown($div){
    //Prettily Animated Swap of this div with it's next sibling
    var h = $div.height(),
        d1 = false,
        d2 = false,
        c = $div.add($div.next()).addClass('rel');
    $div.animate({top:h},1000,'linear',function(){
        d1 = true;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            $div.next().after($div);
            c.removeClass('rel').attr('style','');
            updatePos($div);
        }
    });
    $div.next().animate({top:(-1 * h)},1000,'linear',function(){
        d2 = true;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            $div.next().after($div);
            c.removeClass('rel').attr('style','');
            updatePos($div);
        }
    });
}
function sendUp($div){
    //Prettily Animated Swap of this div with it's previous sibling
    var h = $div.prev().height(),
        d1 = false,
        d2 = false,
        c = $div.add($div.prev()).addClass('rel');
    $div.animate({top:(-1 * h)},1000,'linear',function(){
        d1 = true;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            $div.after($div.prev());
            c.removeClass('rel').attr('style','');
            updatePos($div);
        }
    });
    $div.prev().animate({top:h},1000,'linear',function(){
        d2 = true;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            $div.after($div.prev());
            c.removeClass('rel').attr('style','');
            updatePos($div);
        }
    });
}
function updatePos($div){
    var mV = getVN($div), pV, nV;
    if ($div.prev('.pictureinthread').length) {
        pV = getVN($div.prev('.pictureinthread'));
        if (pV < mV) return sendUp($div);
    }
    if ($div.next('.pictureinthread').length) {
        nV = getVN($div.next('.pictureinthread'));
        if (nV > mV) return sendDown($div);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've gone above and beyond!  I really appreciate it, as your answers have helped my client side skill improve.  I haven't had a chance to try this yet in my code but it looks like it will be exactly what I need.  My divs are inline-block not block, but I'm sure I can figure out left/right as opposed to up/down

Comment: Works exceptionally.  I bound it by giving each pictureinthread a unique id, and then onSuccess="updatePos(\$('#pic${pictureInThread.id}'));"

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
$(function(){
    var $wrap = $('#pictureThread');
    function pSort(a,b){
        if (a.vote > b.vote) return -1;
        if (a.vote < b.vote) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    function pictureSort(){
        var pictures = [];
        $('div.pictureinthread').each(function(i,E){
            var P = {div:E,
                 vote:parseInt($(E).find('.voteamount').text(),10)};
            pictures.push(P);
        });
        pictures.sort(pSort);
        $.each(pictures,function(i,E){
            $(E.div).appendTo($wrap);
        });
    }
    pictureSort();
});
```

I build an array of the all of the divs (and capture their vote amount), and then sort the array, and re-insert them into their wrapper in the correct (sorted) order.
The sort function compares the `vote` property of the object in the array.

That presumes a structure like this: (I ommitted tags from your example that don't affect the JS)

```
<div id="pictureThread">
<div class="pictureinthread">
        <div class="picturemeta">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                <div class="voteamount">3</div>
            </a>     
        </div>
</div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of help I was hoping for, thanks.  Could you update your example to add some animation of the divs taking their new places?

Comment: @Pete I'm glad it was helpful to some extent. Unfortunately, it is not suitable for animation. If you watched each step through the last `.each` call you would see _EVERY_ div move, which would not look good animated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would want to collapse them, when they are invisible destroy and create them again in the correct order or switch their contents then expand them.

- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
- http://api.jquery.com/hide/
- http://api.jquery.com/show/

I also encourage you to have a (div/span)wrapper to avoid the whole page collapsing.

Comment: Could you provide a simple working example in JSFiddle or similar?